# Cannot get value bigger than 9 digits and pass the value to another activity

Tags: android, double

How to retrive a number which is more than 9 digits from editText and how to send the value to another activity. I have tried using Double but I am getting the error.

```
            Double cnumber2=0;
            String snumber2 = number2.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
            cnumber2 = Double.parseDouble(snumber2);
```

the error is

```
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366): Process: ks.developers.festoforcollege, PID: 3366
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at ks.developers.festoforcollege.ContactRegister$1.onClick(ContactRegister.java:70)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-04 20:12:37.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: looks like the value from "number2" is empty

Comment: Log the value of `snumber2` and see what it prints.

Comment: number2 is editText and i need to retrive value from editText. And the number is more than 10 digits.

Comment: What value do you get before you call `replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Double cnumber2=0;
 String snumber2 = number2.getText().toString().replace(",", "");
 cnumber2 = Double.parseDouble(snumber2);
```

i think a double is sperated with `.` instead of `,`.

So try either this

```
String snumber2 = number2.getText().toString().replace(".", "");
```

or different approach to parse the double.. like this:

```
double total = Double.parseDouble(jlbTotal.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks bofredo I have got it but it is converted into a real number so how can get that back to an integer. In the next activity.

Comment: if it has more than 9 digits you will most certainly need another primitive type than Integer. Try the type Long

Comment: I have tried using that too but I am not able to get the value of editText to long interger and cannot even send long.